# Can we restrict people from adding liquidty in our token?

Tags: token, blockchain, smartcontracts, erc20, uniswap

Is there a way to make an erc-20 smart contract in which only the owner of the smart contract can add liquidity?

I tried creating a function but it did not worked. The function was very basic tho. Can someone propose a solution?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Show your code and ask a question about the code.

Comment: could you not post a smart contract on fiver and have them make one real fast?